# Converting Seconds to Hours Minutes Seconds Format in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, time

I am trying to convert my data to be shown in Hours, Minutes, and Seconds. I currently have the data being shown in just hours, however, it is rounding up or down due to the way I have it formatted.

The server that I am pulling from pulls the data in seconds, so I have converted it to hours by just simply doing (Sum(AuxTime)/3600.0). But I need it in [H]:mm:ss format.

I tried then just pulling the data straight from the serve in my Access query (AuxTime). Then in my VBA module, I made the number format as follows:

```
 With .PivotFields("Aux_Time")
    .Orientation = 4
    .Function = -4157
    .NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
    .Caption = "Time Spent in Aux Time"
 End With
```

However, that is not putting the data in that format, it is just putting all of the seconds in the hours area.

Is there anything else that I should be doing that I am missing?

Comment: Maybe you should use `hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

Since you've asked about as it relates to VBA...

```
Format(12345.123,"hh:mm:ss")              results in   02:57:07
Format(#12/31/2018 15:32:01#,"hh:mm:ss")   results in   15:32:01
```

The 1st example seems to be your case, doesn't it?

It should do the same in a query.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom function for this. But, first convert the seconds to a time value (86400 seconds per day), then format to text:

```
Display = FormatHourMinuteSecond(CDate(Sum(AuxTime) / 86400))
```

using a function like this:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinuteSecond( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours, minutes, and seconds of datTime
' converted to hours, minutes, and seconds as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03:55# + #20:01:24#
'   returns: 30:05:19
'
' 2014-06-17. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinuteSec  As String
  Dim strHours      As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute and second count when needed.
  strMinuteSec = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2) & strSeparator & Right("0" & CStr(Second(datTime)), 2)
  strHours = strHour & strSeparator & strMinuteSec

  FormatHourMinuteSecond = strHours

End Function  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```