# Time Formatting for MS Access Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out the proper syntax to converting a total of minutes to show properly. For example: if something shows 65 minutes I want it to show 1:05.

What I have been messing with is as follows:

```
Format(Round(DateDiff("n",[StartDate],[DateCompleted]),2),"Short Time")
```

The query has totals turned on as this field is set to Expression. I'm getting strange results with the current criteria.
I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing but I haven't been having much luck. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: Converting elapsed time to H:M:S text is a little more complicated. Review Gustav answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990831/converting-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds-format-in-access-vba

Comment: Another https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-access-convert-hhmmss-to-double-and-back/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you won't exceed 24 hours, you can do it straight:

```
Duration: Format([DateCompleted]-[StartDate],"Short Time")
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!